# How to use rails within Cygwin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cygwin

I have installed rails using rubystack and set env path, so I can use it in cmd. When I try to use it with cygwin I doesn't work (it shouldn't), how to make this rails work on both windows and cygwin env or I have to install it separately.

Comment: Do you have the gem command working within Cygwin?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to install so you can use it in cmd, then you can do this without having to use Cygwin.  You can download and install ruby and rubygems in windows and then use rubygems to install rails and any other gems you need.  You then just have to set the path properly to include the bin directory of the ruby installation and you should be able to use ruby from cmd in windows.  This doesn't directly answer your questions I know, but if you are just looking for rails in the cmd, I hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, but I want it to run within cygwin because e-textediot run it from their (if I don't got this wrong). Now I can't use most rail bundle in e-texteditor, so I want a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: I found two items which fixed the problem I outlined below.**

Firstly

- Run Cygwin’s setup.exe and search for "make"
- Wait for search results
- Install all items which appear (you can do this by clicking near the top of the "tree")

Secondly

- Run Cygwin’s setup.exe and install the rebase package.
- Using the Windows cmd line (yes, it must be the Windows cmd line not cygwin!), run `\cygwin\bin\ash`
- At the ash prompt, run `/bin/rebaseall`

Restart Windows. Run cygwin. Run: `gem install rails`

---

I have installed Ruby via the cygwin setup file. I've also installed "make", "sqlite" and "openssl/openssh".

I've then sucessfully installed Gems by downloading from website, cd into /cygwin/bin/ and then into a temp directory and then running ruby setup.rb.

This all installed perfectly.

Now I run `gem install rails`. It fails producing the following error. I can't find any more info on this. Any help much appreciated.

```
gem install rails
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\ProgramData/gemrc
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/gemrc
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
      0 [main] ruby 524 C:\cygwin\bin\ruby.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\ruby\1.8\i386-cygwin\etc.so to same address as parent: 0x230000 != 0x330000
      0 [main] ruby 524 C:\cygwin\bin\ruby.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\ruby\1.8\i386-cygwin\etc.so to same address as parent: 0x230000 != 0x330000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
023FAEF8  6102796B  (023FAEF8, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
      1 [main] ruby 2736 fork: child 524 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
023FC218  61004F1B  (611A7FAC, 61243684, 00230000, 00330000)
End of stack trace
      1 [main] ruby 2736 fork: child 524 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
1049214 [main] ruby 6948 C:\cygwin\bin\ruby.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\ruby\1.8\i386-cygwin\etc.so to same address as parent: 0x230000 != 0x3D0000
1049214 [main] ruby 6948 C:\cygwin\bin\ruby.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\ruby\1.8\i386-cygwin\etc.so to same address as parent: 0x230000 != 0x3D0000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
023FAEF8  6102796B  (023FAEF8, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
023FB1E8  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
023FC218  61004F1B  (611A7FAC, 61243684, 001055653 [main] ruby 2736 fork: child 6948 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
230000, 003D0000)
End of stack trace
1055653 [main] ruby 2736 fork: child 6948 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
2095819 [main] ruby 6924 C:\cygwin\bin\ruby.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\ruby\1.8\i386-cygwin\etc.so to same address as parent: 0x230000 != 0x360000
2095819 [main] ruby 6924 C:\cygwin\bin\ruby.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap \\?\C:\cygwin\lib\ruby\1.8\i386-cygwin\etc.so to same address as parent: 0x230000 != 0x360000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
023FAEF8  6102796B  (023FAEF8, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
023FB1E8  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
023FC218  61004F1B  (611A7FAC, 61243684, 00230000, 00360000)2103039 [main] ruby 2736 fork: child 6924 - died waiting for dll loading, errno
11

End of stack trace
2103039 [main] ruby 2736 fork: child 6924 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin -I/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-cygwin -I.   -g -O2    -c bcrypt_ext.c
make: gcc: Command not found
make: *** [bcrypt_ext.o] Error 127


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bcrypt-ruby-3.0.1/ext/mri/gem_make.out
```

For your info my ruby and gem versions are below:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [i386-cygwin]

$ gem -v
1.8.10
```

Answer (score -1):

Please visit this site:

[http://www.pluitsolutions.com/2006/03/30/install-ruby-on-rails-ror-on-cygwin](http://www.pluitsolutions.com/2006/03/30/install-ruby-on-rails-ror-on-cygwin/)

However, if you have a different issue leave a comment and we will have a look.